# Mobile responsive navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginning web developer and of course I ran into a problem haha. Was hoping someone could offer suggestions. I am trying to build a responsive mobile navbar but when I click on the menu button and change the size of the my screen, the navbar disappears. I think it's something to do with event handlers in javascript. Can someone help me and let me know where I wrong?

```js
const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar')

document.getElementById('menubutton').addEventListener('click', myFunction);

function myFunction(event){
    if (navbar.style.display==="block") {
        navbar.style.display ="none";
    } else {
        navbar.style.display="block";
    }
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.headermenu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.buttonstyling{
   background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 20px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

.navbar{
    display: none;
    background-color: black;
}

.navbar a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 15px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

#logoheader{
    width: 60%;

}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    .buttonstyling{
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar{
        display: flex;
        background-color: white;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    
    .navbar a{
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
    }

}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="headermenu">
        <button type="button" id="menubutton" class="buttonstyling">
            Menu
        </button>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="">About</a>
        <a href="">Services</a>
        <a href="">Work With Me</a>
        <a href="">Blog</a>
        <a href="">Contact</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: When you click on it you set it to display none

Answer (score 0):

When you use javascript to hard-set `style.display = none`, the element is now going to have that style in every screen size and will ignore any conflicting CSS rules which come after it. What you want to do is create a class which you can add and take away, which has rules that only exist for certain screen sizes.

In this example I added the class `expanded`, which will not be applied to any elements in the media query. Instead the `navbar` will fall back to `display: flex`.

```js
const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar')

document.getElementById('menubutton').addEventListener('click', myFunction);

function myFunction(event){
    if (navbar.classList.contains('expanded')) {
        navbar.classList.remove('expanded');
    } else {
        navbar.classList.add('expanded');
    }
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.headermenu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.buttonstyling{
   background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 20px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

.navbar{
    display: none;
    background-color: black;
}

.expanded {
    display: block;
}

.navbar a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    background-color: unset;
    padding: 15px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

#logoheader{
    width: 60%;

}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    .buttonstyling{
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar{
        display: flex;
        transform: unset;
        background-color: white;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    
    .navbar a{
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
    }

}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="headermenu">
        <button type="button" id="menubutton" class="buttonstyling">
            Menu
        </button>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="">About</a>
        <a href="">Services</a>
        <a href="">Work With Me</a>
        <a href="">Blog</a>
        <a href="">Contact</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```